# Front-end or Back-end Implementation of API?

Tags: design-patterns, php, javascript, web-api

Lets say I want to implement an API from an external website, for example like Dribbble or Last.fm.

I'm fairly new to this new generation of front-end MVC's (angular, etc), and most example's I've seen implement API's in the front-end with use of ajax calls.

So my question is this, is there a benefit of doing this, instead of lets say calling the API requried in the back-end(php)? What are some obvious drawbacks/benefits from each approach?

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Interactivity.

Putting functionality in the browser has the same advantages that putting functionality in any other user interface does, as opposed to just showing static forms: you get to interact with the user in real-time, instead of waiting for the user to fill out the form, submit it to the server, and wait for a full-page response.

Some examples of this:

1. Validating fields as the user types them.
2. Providing real-time display and updates of dashboard data, widgets or graphs.
3. Providing real-time control of and access to server functionality.
4. Allowing for other modes of interaction, such as machine to machine.

And so on.

Imagine a first-person shooter game that didn't have these facilities, that relied on a postback of the entire page for anything to happen.  Wouldn't be very interesting or nimble, would it?

Comment: Can I get a clarification please? 
Do you mean that if the API (say a GET for weather details) were called in the front end (using say, Angular), the page wouldn't need to reload to show the weather data? And thus, it is faster and 'interactive'?